# bit mask left shift

Tags: c, bit-shift

I tried to solve a problem but I don't know if it's the good solution.

Build a mask of type unsigned long with the 14 least significant bits (from the right) set to 1;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
unsigned long mask;
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<14;i++)
        mask|=(1<<i);
    printf("%li",mask);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you didn't simply write `0x3fff` or `0b0011'1111'1111'1111`?

Comment: Clue to avoiding the loop - what happens if you subtract 1 from a number that has precisely 1 bit set to 1, all other bits zero.

Comment: It would probably have been better (for the site) to have edited your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077563/hi-everyone-please-help-bit-manipulation)

Comment: @5gon12eder: One good reason not to use `0b0011'1111'1111'1111` is that it's a syntax error in C (and, I think, in all but the most recent versions of C++).

Comment: You should also be able to "or" the mask with 2^15 - 1 to achieve the same result. I'm not sure on the speed efficiency between the two methods though.

Comment: @KeithThompson It is valid C++14 but I agree the hex version is more readable.

Comment: @5gon12eder: I didn't actually say that it's more readable.

Comment: Also, it appears as if your code works correctly, but you are just unsure whether there's a better solution. This question would probably fit better on [SE CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm puzzled with  "least significant bits" (unambiguous) and the "bits from right" (ambiguous): in the latter case you should probably take into account endianness as well, no ?

Comment: @Christophe endianness refers to byte order, not bit order. And while some systems might *number* their bits backwards, I've never seen a convention where the right-most bit wasn't also the least significant.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Endianess also refers to bit-order. It just most times is not used that way.

Comment: @Olaf please name me just one example so that I may be educated.

Comment: bit order doesn't really matter, as the least addressible unit in C is the byte

Comment: @MarkRansom: I came across 1 or 2 such architectures. At least PPC used to (afaik still does) number the MSB bit 0, thus is big-endian bit-odered, while e.g. ARM and x86 are little-endian bit-ordered. (It's some time ago I read about PPC, so I'm not sure if that still is true). The other was some DSP or FPGA (not sure anymore) implementation. As I wrote: seldom, but still possible.

Comment: The unsigned long will be stored on several bytes. And the 14 least significant bits will be on 2 bytes. Thus On little endian architectures, the the 14 LSB do not correspond to the 14 bits at the right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is better

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
unsigned long mask;
int main()
{
    int num = 14;
    mask = (1 << num) - 1;
    printf("%lu", mask);
    return 0;
}
```

Here `num` is total number of  least significant bits.

**How it Works**

Binary representation of 2^14 = 16348 is   `0000000000000000 0100000000000000‬`(In 32 bit)
and

binary representation of 2^14-1 = 16347  is  `0000000000000000 0011111111111111‬`

So 14 least significant bits set to 1.

Comment: *Why* would this be better?

Comment: The change between this and the OP's question is very minor and hard to notice. Could you point the change out and example why the change would be _better_

Comment: As mask is `unsigned long` so it should be printed with `%lu`.

Comment: Since the OP was asking about constructing the bit mask, not about printing it, that would have been better as a comment. (It wouldn't even be an answer if the question were less vague.)

Comment: @KeithThompson, Thank's for your suggestion, I'm edited to new version.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but can you explain me how this works? how does (1<< num) - 1 works?

Comment: @DariusIonut Same reason 1,000 - 1 is 999. If you want N 9's in base 10, you take (10^N)-1. If you want N 1's in base 2, you take (2^N)-1.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thank you, I understand now :) Thank you all

Comment: @SolaineCharron Thank you for your help! But if I want to make the same thing but with most significant bits, from left, can I do it in this mode?

Comment: @DariusIonut if you need bits from the left, I'll give you a hint: `~`

Comment: I think @MarkRansom is getting at `~(-1<<n)`, but that may only go for 2's complement.... wait he said from left... still then just subtract n from number of bits and don't negate.